# Error occurred when trying to execute this swap in Uniswap V2

Tags: tokens, error

I’m trying to buy AHOUSE/weth and I get the “error occurred when trying to execute this swap” message. I try buying it with usdc, and eth. I try increasing the gas but nothing worked. I looked on etherscan and AHOUSE was on there and I assume that if it is on there then it isn’t a scam token.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Being on etherscan absolutely doesnt mean the token isnt a scam (actually you can't really not be on etherscan as long as you've deployed your token on mainnet). In that case, the contract code is not verified, which doesnt allow us to check if its a scam or not, but it appears people can indeed sell the token ( https://etherscan.io/token/0xB125CcEb9C6e349217d09B069a8d88DBEAcF06E5#tokenTrade ). Try to increase the slippage maybe